# How to create a English Spell Checker and get suggestions accordingly?

Tags: android, spell-checking, spelling

I want to develop an app which checks the spellings when an user is writing in an edittext with a red mark for wrong spelling and give suggestions accordingly.I tried this code but not working on Device this code works on to emulator but not working on any phone.  Please suggest me some reference

Please Help. Thanks in advance

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
   SpellCheckerSession.SpellCheckerSessionListener
{
 Button b1;
 TextView tv1;
 EditText ed1;
 private SpellCheckerSession mScs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    //tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

}
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    final TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);
    mScs = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, null, this, true);
}

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (mScs != null)
    {
        mScs.close();
    }
}

public void onGetSuggestions(final SuggestionsInfo[] arg0)
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < arg0.length; ++i)
    {
        // Returned suggestions are contained in SuggestionsInfo
        final int len = arg0[i].getSuggestionsCount();
        sb.append('\n');

        for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j)
        {
            sb.append("," + arg0[i].getSuggestionAt(j));
        }


        sb.append(" (" + len + ")");
    }
    mScs.getSuggestions(new TextInfo(ed1.getText().toString()), 3);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
           // tv1.append(sb.toString());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onGetSentenceSuggestions(SentenceSuggestionsInfo[] arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```